# HTTPS connection is not working [Spring Boot]

Tags: https, spring-boot

I am setting up a HTTPS server using Spring boot. I followed the [Configure SSL on Spring Boot Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl).

My application.properties file is as follows.

```
# SSL
server.port = 8443
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = rootroot
```

But when I access https://localhost:8443 . The server returns no response and server is temporarily down.

Can you guide me what is going wrong?

Comment: Well, anything in the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the answer. I was using the keystore.jks generated from another machine instead of generating in server machine.

Now I solved the problem by using the keystore generated by keytool on server machine and everything went well.

Anyway, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your information did not work for me, then I've did some researches and now it's working after I followed the below steps:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <mycert.crt> -inkey <mykey.key> -out <mycert.p12> -name tomcat -CAfile <myca.ca> -caname root -chain
```

(I ran the above command to generate a pkcs12 in my digitalcert, which the only file that does not exists yet is the mycert.p12)

After that I've copied the mycert.p12 to src/main/resources

And finally this is my application.properties file configuration:

```
server.context-path=/cv2
server.port=8880
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:java_admin_checkverification_com.p12
```

And now everything is working like a charm!

PS: The configuration server.ssl.key-store was not working for me when I was at the version 1.2.4, because it was not finding the file in the classpath at all... Always throwing FileNotFoundException, so I updated to 1.3.5, with the above configurations and now everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and adding the key-store-type fixed it:

> server.ssl.key-store-type: JKS

Answer (score 0):

"Tomcat requires the key store (and trust store if you’re using one) to be directly accessible on the filesystem, i.e. it cannot be read from within a jar file. This limitation doesn’t apply to Jetty and Undertow."

by default tomcat is used

Answer (score 0):

If someone has same issue -
my settings are

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:certs/localhost.keystore
server.ssl.key-store-password=somepass
server.ssl.key-password=somepass
```

I had a problem with my request - Ive been sending request to 127.0.0.1:8443, but my certificate had name localhost! I fixed request to localhost:8443 and all went right.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling my cert with certbot fixed it for me. Just ran `certbot` and `1: Attempt to reinstall this existing certificate`. I already had my config setup like the other answers. I'm not sure how this fixed it, but I figure I'd leave this answer here. I'm using Nginx.